# How do I segment my users in Google Analytics to show only users who have triggered an event "X" times?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to segment my users in Google Analytics to show only users who have performed a specific event "X" time(s).

I can only seem to segment them by either "they did, or did not, trigger this event".  Current Filter for this: "Filter, Users, Include, Event Action exactly matches 'SentMessage'"

What I tried from here, was to add an "AND" statement, to say "AND, Event Value, Per User, >= 1, 5, 10, ect..."

However when I apply this "AND" statement, the only value that returns any numbers is "0".  If it selects 1+, it shows me 0% of users.  I'm thinking this "Event Value" is not being linked to the filtered event above, but I'm not sure why, and I can't figure out how.

Anyone know?  Huge block for me right now :/

Comment: I don't think that Google Analytics supports segments based on number of times triggering an event.   The "event value" is for eCommerce events where you send a numeric value for the event such as "added product to cart" with a value of $9.88.

Answer (score 1):

You can segment users who have activated the event, and add the metric "total events" to the filter, and set to the number you want (total events = X).

The problem with this is it will return you all the users that activated the event X times during their entire lifetime (not just the selected data range).

There is a workaround if X is 10 or less, which is including users who went through a sequence of X steps with the event.

The limitation with this is X can't be more than 10, and it will only count through the previous 90 days, and you can't change that number to anything less (or more, or dynamically with the data range).